# Uncaught TypeError: on null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax for getting tabular format in my page. The problem is it was working, currently I encounter this problem

### My code

```
$.each(res,function(index,row){ 
              
      console.log(row.bookable);
//{id: 2, slug: "dire_international_queen", organization_id: 1, roomtype_id: 5, no_bed: "2", …}

      console.log(row.bookable.slug); // it show what i expect (working), but **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slug' of null"**


}
```

### Error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slug' of null

Comment: seems you are trying to retrieve value before ajax has returned result

Comment: it was working while it just happens now, its related with jquery update or other things??

Comment: There are not enough details to reproduce the problem. It can't work and not work at the same time. Please create a [mcve] with more relevant details like how you call the relevant ajax request and get its results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using for each So I suppose you are getting array results in ajax response. 
check two things here.

```
(row.bookable !=null) and (row.bookable.slug !=null)
```

it usually happened because you are getting some value null for "bookable" property

```
$.each(res,function(index,row){ 
    if(row.bookable!=null)
     {
      console.log(row.bookable);
     }
//{id: 2, slug: "dire_international_queen", organization_id: 1, roomtype_id: 5, no_bed: "2", …}
      //check here
      if(row.bookable !=null && row.bookable.slug!=null)
      console.log(row.bookable.slug); 

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an object lists of data in the `res` variable. You are getting the error because somewhere in the look your program unable to find the slug property.

Use `hasOwnProperty()` to check if the property exists, then apply the related action.

```
$.each(res,function(index,row){ 
    if ( row.bookable.hasOwnProperty('slug') ) {
        console.log(row.bookable.slug);
    }
}
```

Take a look to learn in the details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty